# Powerpoint Animation Related

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I am working on a presentation & added 3 objects with 3 different animations in a sequence.

I have been able to apply animation, however i want them to animate continuously one after another (continuous rewind in a sequence).

Answer (score 0):

All right. So it sounds like you already have the animations timing correct where the end of one causes the start of the other. If not, go to the animations section and on the advanced animation portion open the animation pane.

Right click the object you are working with and select timing (This is where you can sync them up if you don't have them starting each other. Have object one start at 0 secs, object 2 at 1 sec, etc.)

One of the selection options is called repeat and choose until end of slide to then have the timer continuously go through.